# SSIS Foreach Loop Container to read files and load into Dynamic 365 causes VS2019 geting crashed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, recordset, foreach-loop-container

I'm trying to load records from CRM 2011 (on-premise) to Dynamic 365 using foreach loop container. After a while (sometime after 15 k records another time after 19k or 17 k records from a total of 71k records) Visual Studio crashes and then restarts. I have to kill the debug task in the task manager for the next execution of the package.

My package looks like this:

[image: my SSIS package]

First I load all the records for Foreach loop task into a Recordset destination and save all the records in a variable `ID_narocila_iz_dodatni_naslovi`.

[image: Recordset Destination]

Then I use this variable in Fooreach ADO Enumerator.

[image: Foreachloop - Collection]

[image: Foreachloop - Variable Mappings]

[image: Foreachloop - Expressions]

I can't figure out what is wrong here. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!